# Get post id from widget in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a sidebar (test-sidebar) that contains widgets with custom posts.

[image]

How can I can get posts from sidebar (widgets)?
I don`t want render post only get their IDs

I am using WordPress Version 4.9.6

Comment: Hi Vadim. Can you give more context on what you want the post ID for and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't with the built in WordPress widgets.

You will need to create your own widget using the [WordPress Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). From there you will be able to develop a widget to complete whatever task you want. Otherwise it will be a trip to the [WordPress plugin repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) to see is someone is sharing a plugin doing what you want to do.

On a side note, you may also want to look at building a [custom WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). This will allow you to pull in whatever posts you want and then manipulate them however, within the body of the page.